# Using shell variable in psql command

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell

I need some help into sending a shell variable to a psql -c query inside a .sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

    timeStamp=`date +%s`
    timeStampLast24H= expr $timeStamp - 86400

    psql -U postgres -c "COPY (SELECT atribute FROM table WHERE ts>$timeStampLast24H) TO stdout DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER; > (...)"
```

I'm doing this to get only rows from the last day because the person who created the database used `rectimestamp` as an integer, and normal functions from postgres won't work (`now()-interval 'Given_Period'`, for example).

Changing "$timeStampLast24H" by something that makes postgres understand an integer that corresponds exactly to the timestamp in from the last 24h is also ok for me. If I use an exact timestamp in its place, the query works well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assignment

```
timeStampLast24H= expr $timeStamp - 86400
```

is incorrect.

Notice how it differs from this assignment?

```
timeStamp=`date +%s`
```

You added a space after the `=` and left out the backticks or `$()` wrapping.

Fix those problems and your issue will likely go away. As it is you are putting no value into your query.

Comment: But I can print timeStampLast24H normally with an echo!

Comment: Now with the code in your post you can't. See http://ideone.com/wx7H5f Or if you can then it had a value from before that code. You might think an `echo` right after the "assignment" line is working but that's actually the `expr` call outputting it.

Comment: Then should it be `timeStampLast24H=expr $timeStamp-86400`?

Comment: Yes, just like the first assignment. Or, to use the better behaved, better nesting, modern format `timeStampLast24H=$(expr $timeStampNow-86400)`. Updating to not use `expr` would be good too. `timeStampLast24H=$(($timeStampNow-86400))`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. This stackoverflow thing is awesome! Thanks a lot bro